# How to use multisampling with "return" in a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, multisampling

I draw transparent figures by depth peeling, the result is ugly when I render to multisample (a grid appears)

```
vec4 fragColor = texelFetch(frontTexture, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0); 
if (gl_FragCoord.z < nearestDepth) {
// Skip this depth in the peeling algorithm
return;
}
fragColor += someColor;
```

Without "if return" everything is alright (but I need this "if"). The grid is exactly the same as when I use mipmapping with non-uniform flow control.

Comment: Apparently you actually need the depths you're skipping.

Comment: Everything is alright without multisampling.

Comment: I hope `fragColor` is not the final `out` variable ... those should be changed just once and any code after the write might be optimized out by **GLSL** implementation.  btw may be you just want `discard;` instead of the `return;` My bet is that you are returning from `main` instead of subroutine and the shader is not compiled due it ... but we can just guess as we do not have the context your chunk of code is chopped from ...

Comment: @-Spektre Yes, fragColor is the final out variable, but everything is alright without multisampling. Yes, I am returning from main, but I get the shader from a classic article about depth peeling.

Comment: @-Spektre I have corrected (now final out variable changed just once), it did not help.

Comment: @GeorgeCherevichenko if you looked at the GLSL logs you would probably see the problem right away. IIRC `return` from main is not allowed. That is what `discard;` is for change the `return;` for `discard;` ... its meaning is: do not write the fragment color instead throw it away. Also do not add `-` to the `@` it invalidates the nick ID and site will not notify the user ...

Comment: @Spektre: "*those should be changed just once and any code after the write might be optimized out by GLSL implementation.*" That is not how it works. You can write to an output variable as many times as you want. The last value is the one kept. Now yes, it may optimize away *previous* writes to the output, but not the last one.

Comment: @NicolBolas good to know how it should work ... However I had problems with it on Intel gfx cards in the past ... that is why I taught so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Available only in the fragment language, gl_FragCoord is an input variable that contains the window relative coordinate (x, y, z, 1/w) values for the fragment. If multi-sampling, this value can be for any location within the pixel [**!!!**]

P.S. Depth peeling use strict depth comparison, it is impossible if we get depth "for any location within the pixel". Instead of

```
if (gl_FragCoord.z < nearestDepth)
```

use

```
if (gl_FragCoord.z < nearestDepth - 0.0001)
```

(it is the first rough solution)